# How to use refresh token by using Keycloak Admin REST API

Tags: java, jboss, redhat, keycloak, redhat-sso

I'm trying to use [Keycloak Admin REST API SDK](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/integration/admin-client).

Then, I want to use refresh token to generate access token.
I know that the following code code can generate access token by refresh token.

```
val token = Keycloak.getInstance(serverUrl,
  realmName,
  userName,
  password,
  clientId,
  clientSecret)
  .tokenManager()
  .refreshToken()
```

But this code can only work on TokenManager.
I want to use any refresh token like following code by admin user.

```
// I hope to call token endpoint -> /realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token?grant_type=refresh_token...
val accessToken = tokenManager.refresh(String refreshToken);
```

Could any SDK Class refresh token as I want?

Comment: I'm also looking for refresh token by java client

Comment: I am also cannot find any solution